# Does getElementsByTagName return ALL child nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

So let's say we have the following XML structure:

```
<property>
    <label>Label 1</label>
    <value>value 1</label>
</property>
<property>
    <label>Label 2</label>
    <value>value 2</label>
</property>
<!-- more of these -->
```

Provided that we have correctly loaded the XML document into variable `var xml`, does `xml.getElementsByTagName("property")` return ALL `property`, `label`, `value` nodes OR just `property` nodes with no children?

Why I'm asking this is, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
var props = xml.getElementsByTagName("property");
var labels = props[0].getElementsByTagName("label");
```

If the function will not return any `label` or `value` nodes, what's the best way to get that done?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `xml.querySelectorAll("property label")` to retrieve all label objects inside a property object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) method “Returns `NodeList` of all *descendant* `Elements` with a given tag name”. So `getElementsByTagName("property")` returns all children, children of children, etc., that have the tag name `property`, no matter what the content of such a node is. It does not of course return any node with some different tag name.

So yes, the code

```
var props = xml.getElementsByTagName("property");
var labels = props[0].getElementsByTagName("label");
```

does what you seem to want to do: it assigns to `labels` a (live) list of `label` children of the first `property` element in the document, provided that there is at least one `property` element. (So for robustness, you might wish to check e.g. that `props.length > 0` before proceeding to the second statement.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is help you

```
var props = xml.getElementsByTagName("property");
var eleChild = props .childNodes;
for( i = 0 , j = eleChild.length; i < j ; i++ ){
    if( eleChild[ i ].className == "autodropdown" ){
        YOUr_SCRIPT
    }
}
```